# a minecraft bot that sends messages that are said in minecraft chat in a discord channel

Tags: javascript, discord, minecraft, discord.js

Hello i am pretty new to javascript and i am trying to make a minecraft bot that logs the chat and sends the messages that are said in the chat to a discord channel.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const client = new Discord.client();

var bot = Mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 62146,
    email: "username",
    password: "password",
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {
    if (username === bot.username) return;
    channels.get("540620424426422272").send(message)
});

on("message", function(message) {
.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: What is your question?  Is something in this code not working? (And if so, which part, and what happens when you try to run it?)

Comment: `on("message"` needs to be `bot.on("message"`

Comment: `.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)` this line does not look like valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write

```
client.on("message"....)
```

And where comes the variable channels from? Maybe:

```
message.channels.get("540620424426422272").send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing multiple things here, if you just want to forward the messages from Minecraft to a Discord channel, there is no need to handle the `message` event emitted from the Discord API, just the `chat` event emitted by Mineflayer. Be careful when defining your Discord client as you want to do `const client = Discord.Client();` not `const client = Discord.client();`. You cannot just do `.channels.get()("500693869684326430").send(message)` in your event handler either. camen6ert suggested to use `message.channels.get("540620424426422272").send(message)` as a possible solution however this would not work as you're wanting to use the event emitted by Mineflayer, not Discord, when you want to get a specific channel ID, I would suggest using `client.channels.get('ID').send('Message content');`

Try this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var bot = Mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 62146,
    email: "username",
    password: "password",
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {
    if (username === bot.username) return;
    client.channels.get("540620424426422272").send(message)
});

client.login('token');
```